# Add BCC to Magento sendNewAccountEmail()

Tags: magento

I've usually been able to find the Magento answers I need either here or at the Magento forums, but I've tried all the solutions I've found thus far, to no avail.

We have a preliminary screening form for company customers. Only when they've been approved by Sales will we create a Magento storefront account for them. I've rewritten the account creation pages and have that working fine, including sending the new customer their New Account Email. I simply can't get the system to send us a BCC for our records to confirm that registration.

The information in the following post seems outdated, at least I can't find the quoted lines of code in  /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php or in a search of the app folder:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/25535/

I've also tested solutions in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email but no luck. Can anybody direct me towards a current solution for Magento Community 1.7 to add a BCC to a New Account email?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::_sendEmailTemplate()` check this lines:

```
$emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
$emailInfo->addTo($this->getEmail(), $this->getName());
```

`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info` has a method addBcc, too.

Comment: Thank you.  I duplicated the $emailInfo->addTo($this->getEmail(), $this->getName()); line and replaced the arguments with the email address and name of Sales. It generates a full new email, not a BCC, but that works fine for me. Appreciate the pointer.

Comment: And now that I've changed the addTo to addBCC, that works also, and better for my purposes.  Thank you again.